# What is the difference between sequential consistency and atomicity?

Tags: java, c++, atomic, volatile

I read that  java volatile are sequential consistent but not atomic.
For atomicity java provides different library.

Can someone explain  difference between two, in simple english ?

(I believe the question scope includes C/C++ and hence adding those language tags to get bigger audience.)

Comment: I don't think that `volatile` provides the same guarantee in C/C++ as in Java. In particular, I don't think it provides in C what you call sequential consistency (i.e. that the memory fence applies to other variables) - TBC.

Comment: @assylias I didnt meant to say volatile has same meaning in C/C++. I am sure it doesn't. I was referring to the concept of 'sequential consistency and atomicity' which is common between c/C++ and Java.
In C/C++ volatile keyword stops optimization of the variable usage and  not used for maintaining sequential-consistency between operations that were specified before the operation with a volatile variable..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine those two variables in a class:

```
int i = 0;
volatile int v = 0;
```

And those two methods

```
void write() {
    i = 5;
    v = 2;
}

void read() {
    if (v == 2) { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

The volatile semantics guarantee that `read` will either print 5 or nothing (assuming no other methods are modifying the fields of course). If `v` were not volatile, `read` might as well print 0 because `i = 5` and `v = 2` could have been reordered. I guess that's what you mean by sequential consistency, which has a broader meaning.

On the other hand, volatile does not guarantee atomicity. So if two threads call this method concurrently (v is the same `volatile int`):

```
void increment() {
    v++;
}
```

you have no guarantee that v will be incremented by 2. This is because `v++` is actually three statements:

```
load v;
increment v;
store v;
```

and because of thread interleaving v could only be incremented once (both thread will load the same value).

Comment: It would be complete answer if you can add an example that will demonstrate something that is atomic and sequential.  Can we do that without using  mutex ?

Comment: Can't update right now but yes, so cslled lock free algorithms use CAS operations to provide atomicity. It is used by all the AtomicXXX classes in java.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have these two variables:

```
public int a = 0;
public volatile int b = 0;
```

And suppose one thread does

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
```

If another thread reads these values and sees that b == 2, then it's guaranteed to also see a == 1.

But the reading thread could see `a == 1` and `b == 0`, because the two writes are not part of an atomic operation, so the reading thread might see the change made to `a` before the first thread has assigned a value to `b`.

To make these two writes atomic, you would need to synchronize the access to these two variables:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
}

...

synchronized (lock) {
    System.out.println("a = " + a + "; b = " + b);
}
```

And in this case, the reading thread will see `a == 0` and `b == 0`, or `a == 1` and `b == 2`, but never the intermediate state.

Comment: +1, but you're not really saying "this is sequential consistency" and "this is atomicity".

Comment: Yes, I assumed this was obvious. But assylias answer is clearer and better than mine anyway.